# Getting selected text of a select listbox using JQuery when I already have the select object in hand

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is an easy one, a true newbie question:

I know that it's possible to get the text of the selection option like this

```
$('#selectBoxId option:selected').val();
```

But what if I already have the select object in my hand?

e.g.

```
var select = $('#selectBoxId');
```

What comes next? this is the right way?

```
select.find('option:selected').val();
```

Comment: probably `select.val()` will be enough

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just `select.val();` is enough. It will give you the selected `value`.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HsgpK/)**

If you want the selected option `text` then your need to do

```
select.find('option:selected').text();
```

Or

```
select.find('option:selected').html();
```